# Colloquial Equivalent of: Speedy Gonzales

Tags: translation

If people are very fast, or do things quickly, sometimes we will refer to such a person as `Speedy Gonzales` in English?

Are there similar references for people in Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Speedy Gonzales` as a cartoon character is translated to `飞毛腿冈萨雷斯`. Not many Chinese know this cartoon character, but `飞毛腿` as a noun can be used to describe people running very fast. It literally means `flying hairy legs`.

Less frequently seen but still recognizable, you can use `神行太保`. It's a nickname for a 水浒 character who is known to be able to run very fast. It literally means `miraculously walking prime minister`. In fact his job is the messenger.

Comment: If I then, likewise, called someone 戴宗 would they get it?

Comment: @user3306356 The nickname is better known. Even for people who haven't read 水浒, they may have heard of `神行太保` somewhere. I can't say the same for `戴宗`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if a man does something very fast (without considering the things are done badly or not), you can say him/her is a **急先锋**.

However, if a man is entitled as this phrase, this means he/she does things carelessly (frequently).

Comment: How about just fast **not** careless?

Comment: @user3306356 That would be 雷厉风行, speedy and decisive execution.